# Packets loss normal over wifi 2.4 ghz?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have bought a new router (netgear n600) and i did some test with the laptop of my friend.. and i was wondering if its normal that on 350 packets.. 3 got loss over a wifi connection.

I am connected over WPA2 without SSID diffusing.

[image: network]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That appears to be within [acceptable parameters](https://kb.netgear.com/1037/Improving-wireless-range-Testing) according to netgear. I would probably use something like [meraki wifistumbler](http://tools.meraki.com/stumbler) to check the channels used by wireless networks in the area, and pick an empty band if possible

Comment: The tool doesnt work i am missing something ? it say 0 network found.

Comment: Works fine for me, but if that dosen't work inSIDDER is an alternative http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/